# Java pass a string variable as a function in a callback

Tags: java, java-8, vert.x

How can I pass a method class variable in a callback?

I have following code:

```
PostsController postController = new PostsController();
router.get("/").handler(postController::index);
```

But my controller will be dynamic, how can I pass dynamic class and its function.
I tried following code

```
Class controller = Class.forName("some.package"+controllerName); //PostsController
Method[] methods = controller.getMethods();
//some loop
Method m = methods[i]; // This is the index method of my controller
router.get(somePath).handler(m); // How can I pass my method m as callback?
```

PostsController

```
public class PostsController {

    @Route(method="get", path = "/")
    public void index(RoutingContext routingContext){
        routingContext.response()
                .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .end(Json.encodePrettily("{}"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you not need to guarantee that all your controllers have this `index` method? Solve that by making your controllers extend some interface which requires that index method.

Comment: index function will be their, but there will be also some custom functions, thats why I want to make it dynamic

Comment: Yes, your custom functions can all be declared in the file, so long as that file implements the interface. The JVM, however, doesn't know you can guarantee that your file has that method. You can make it guarantee that by having all controllers implement a common interface.

Comment: I have edited my question, please read it once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be to use an `interface` defining the common functionality, e.g.

```
public interface Controller {
    void index(RoutingContext routingContext);
}
public class PostsController implements Controller {
    @Route(method="get", path = "/")
    public void index(RoutingContext routingContext){
        routingContext.response()
                .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .end(Json.encodePrettily("{}"));
    }
}
```

```
Class<? extends Controller> controllerType =
    Class.forName("some.package"+controllers.getString(i))
         .asSubclass(Controller.class);
Controller controller=controllerType.newInstance();
Handler<RoutingContext> h=controller::index;
```

Of course, this doesn’t interact with the annotation based processing. A dynamic solution would look like

```
Class<?> controllerType = Class.forName("some.package"+controllers.getString(i));
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup=MethodHandles.lookup();
Method[] methods = controllerType.getMethods();
Object instance = null;
for (Method m : methods) {
    Route annotation = m.getAnnotation(Route.class);
    if (annotation != null) {
        if(instance == null) instance = controllerType.newInstance();
        Handler<RoutingContext> handler
            =createHandler(lookup, instance, m, RoutingContext.class);
        router.get(annotation.path()).handler(handler);
    }
}
```

```
static <T> Handler<T> createHandler(MethodHandles.Lookup lookup,
        Object instance, Method m, Class<T> arg) throws Throwable {

    MethodHandle mh=lookup.unreflect(m);
    MethodType t=mh.type();
    Class<?> receiver=t.parameterType(0);
    if(t.parameterCount()!=2
    || !receiver.isAssignableFrom(instance.getClass())
    || !t.parameterType(1).isAssignableFrom(arg))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(m+" not suitable for Handler<"+arg.getName()+'>');
    t=t.dropParameterTypes(0, 1);
    return (Handler)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "accept",
        MethodType.methodType(Handler.class, receiver),
        t.changeParameterType(0, Object.class), mh, t)
        .getTarget().invoke(instance);
}
```

This works under certain assumption about your `Handler` interface which you didn’t specify. If it was defined like, `interface Handler<T> extends Consumer<T> {}`, it will work out of the box. Otherwise, you have to adapt `"accept"` to the actual name of your functional interface’s function method. And if the type parameter has a bound, you’ll have to change the `t.changeParameterType(0, Object.class)` line to use the actual bound (the `Handler`’s parameter type after type erasure).

Generally, this requires great care as you don’t have immediate error feedback. In the worst case, errors will only be detected when the call back actually is invoked (with certain arguments).

In principle, you could also just create a lambda expression encapsulating a Reflective invocation of the method, i.e.

```
Handler<RoutingContext> handler=rc -> { try {
    m.invoke(capturedInstance, rc);
} catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }};
```

but this doesn’t change the fact that you will be detecting errors only very late…

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but its throwing me this error:
`java.lang.AbstractMethodError: io.vertx.lib.AppVertical$$Lambda$28/647430455.handle(Ljava/lang/Object;)V`

Comment: As said, you have to adapt the method name: `"accept"` → `"handle"`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked :)
Interface looks clean and easy, but what is the cleaner way to go further if I have dynamic methods in controller.

Comment: Well for frameworks with dynamic discovery, some Reflection is unavoidable. I use code similar to the `createHandler` method as well. It’s important to have such things at an isolated place, rather than having reflective operations spread throughout the application. If used correctly, it works as smooth as compile-time method references.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i can see, is that you need to create an instance of your class.

```
Class controller = Class.forName("some.package"+controllers.getString(i));
Object myInstance = controller.newInstance();
```

Then you get your Method from it, and call it :

```
Method myMethod = ...
myMethod.invoke(myInstance, null);  // or with some params
```

If you only need to call "index", you could also make your controller implement a common interface, and then :

```
MyInterface myInterface = (MyInterface) myInstance;
myInterface.index();
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: I tried this `router.get(annotation.path()).handler(((Handler<RoutingContext>) m.invoke(controller.newInstance(),null)));` it throws an error as `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`

Comment: obviously, since you index method avec a parameter, you need to provide it.

Comment: but invoke will actually execute the function, I want to pass it as callback. Handler will provide parameters the callback function

Comment: Then you need your handler to call invoke.

Comment: I don't know what is your router object, but the logic to call your method must be there, in the `handler(..)` method. If it's some framework class, you probably need to make your own.

Comment: I am using vert.x, the only thing is that I need to pass Method variable `m` to that handler as callback, but dont know exactly how to do it

Comment: You did it. But then, vert.x must know that you give him a method (and instance) to call. If not a native behavior, you need to create your own stuff. Good luck.